# How to send http request to python flask server from desktop application?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have configured python server using flask framework.
Now I want to send request to server from my desktop application.
My server location is : `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

I have written code which work from browser but i want to access that code from my desktop app.

```python
import flask,flask.views import os import functools 
app=flask.Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key="xyz" users={'pravin':'abc'}
class Main(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return flask.render_template('index.html')
    def post(self):
        if 'logout' in flask.request.form:
            flask.session.pop('username',None)
            return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))
        required=['username','passwd']
        for r in required:
        if r not in flask.request.form:
            flask.flash("Error: {0} is required.".format(r))
            return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))

        username=flask.request.form['username']
        password=flask.request.form['passwd']
        if username in users and users[username]==password:
            flask.session['username']=username
        else:
            flask.flash("Username doesn`t exist or incorrect password.")

        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))

app.add_url_rule("/",view_func=Main.as_view("index"),methods=["GET","POST"])
app.debug=True
app.run()
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to use a python library to access the url from the desktop app.

Try [requests module](http://kennethreitz.com/requests-python-http-module.html). It makes working with http request easy and describes itself as `an elegant and simple HTTP library for Python, built for human beings.`

Sample code:

```
    >>> r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
    >>> r.status_code
        <Response [200]>
```

Comment: Why do you recommend an external module without a reason?

Comment: @BlaXpirit Because its easy to use!

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to use the python standard library [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) ?

Or the even better [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/).

Here is a GET test (inspired by [httplib2 examples](http://httplib2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/html/libhttplib2.html#examples)) :

```
import httplib2
h = httplib2.Http()
resp, content = h.request("http://127.0.0.1:5000/")
```